# How to return function in Dart?

Tags: function, dart

As **Dart docs** `describe` it, as this being **purely OOP language**, `Functions` are also `object`.

This can be done in JS like this :

```
function functionReturningFunctionJS() {
  return function functionReturnedByFunctionJS() {
      return "This is function returned by function";
  }
}
```

But I could not return function from function like this n dart:

```
Function functionReturningFunctionDart() {
  return  functionReturnedByFunctionDart(){
    return "This is function Returned By function";
  }
}
```

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please refer the below add function which returns the another function (or closure).

```
void main() {
  Function addTen = add(10);
  print(addTen(5)); //15
  print(add(10)(5)); //15
}

Function add(int a) {
    int innerFunction(b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    return innerFunction;
}
```

With anonymous function:

```
void main() {
  Function addTen = add(10)
  print(addTen(5)); //15
  print(add(10)(5)); //15
}

Function add(int a) {
    return (b) => a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can return function literals or function-containing variables, but not function declarations. To return a function declaration you can assign it to a local variable (tear-off it off) and then return it.

```
// OK
String Function() makeFunction() {
  return () {
    return 'Hello';
  };
}

// Also OK
String Function() makeFunction2() {
  String myInnerFunction() {
    return 'Hello';
  }
  final myFunction = myInnerFunction; // make a tear-off.
  return myFunction;
}
```

And you can call the function like :

```
var abc = makeFunction2();
print(abc());
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Jonah